# Angular 2 application with refreshing data in real time

Tags: angular, observable

I am using angular4.

I am trying to Real time update using observable.

Here is my code

First i import `observable`

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { AnonymousSubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
    import { ApiServiceProvider } from '../../providers/api-service/api-service';

    constructor(public apiService:ApiServiceProvider){} 
    ngOnInit(){
        this.getAllNeighbours();
    }
    getAllNeighbours(){
    //Get Apartment User
    this.addNeighbours=[];
    this.postsSubscription=this.apiService.getApartmentUser(this.currentUserApartId).subscribe(users=>{
        var apartmentUsers=users.json();
        this.subscribeToData();

        //Get Apartments flats
        this.apiService.getApartmentFlats(this.currentUserApartId).subscribe(flats=>{
            var apartmentFlats=flats.json();
            for(var i in apartmentFlats){
                if(apartmentFlats[i].USER_ID.toString() != this.currentUserId.toString()){
                    var filterUser=apartmentUsers.filter(u=>u.id.toString() === apartmentFlats[i].USER_ID.toString());
                    console.log(filterUser);
                    if(filterUser.length != 0)
                        this.addNeighbours.push({
                            username:filterUser[0].FIRST_NAME + filterUser[0].LAST_NAME,
                            flatno:apartmentFlats[i].FLAT_NO,
                            userid:apartmentFlats[i].USER_ID
                        })
                }
                if(apartmentFlats[i].TENANT_ID.toString() != this.currentUserId.toString()){
                    var filterUser=apartmentUsers.filter(u=>u.id.toString() === apartmentFlats[i].TENANT_ID.toString());
                    if(filterUser.length != 0)
                        this.addNeighbours.push({
                            username:filterUser[0].FIRST_NAME + filterUser[0].LAST_NAME,
                            flatno:apartmentFlats[i].FLAT_NO,
                            userid:apartmentFlats[i].USER_ID
                        })
                }
            }
            this.loading=false;

        })
    });
  }

  subscribeToData(){
    this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(()=>{
        this.getAllNeighbours();
    })
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.postsSubscription) {
      this.postsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.timerSubscription) {
      this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

First I get Flats list after I get users list.then i combined data and filter and these values are pushed into `addNeighbours` array.

I am using `this.subscribeToData();`.Its used for every time called `getAllNeighbours()` and update to UI.

Everything is worked fine.My UI is every 5 seconds Update.But at the same time My UI is every 5 seconds like blinking.How can i fix this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the getApartmentFlats() service method gets data from somewhere, and it takes time to get the response. If you set this.addNeighbours=[] before the service even calls the method, then you are going to have a blank template because the array is empty before the observable can be processed, causing the page to blink. The solution is to move this.addNeighbours=[] to after the observable is returned, but before you populate the new data.

```
    getAllNeighbours() {
        //Get Apartment User
        this.postsSubscription=this.apiService.getApartmentUser(this.currentUserApartId).subscribe(users=>{
            var apartmentUsers=users.json();
            this.subscribeToData();

            //Get Apartments flats
            this.apiService.getApartmentFlats(this.currentUserApartId).subscribe(flats=>{
                var apartmentFlats=flats.json();
                this.addNeighbours = [];

                ......          

                this.loading = false;

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi,@Daniel are you there?I have one doubt.

Comment: Yup, what would you like to ask?